# How can I get Jenkins SCM polling to accumulate changes?

Tags: jenkins

I have a job that takes a while to complete and is quite resource heavy. I only ever want to run one instance of the job at a time, and only if there are new SCM changes.

I set it up with an SCM trigger and left off the checkbox "Execute concurrent builds if necessary".

The problem I have is that it queues up the next build on the first SCM change it detects.

What I want is that whenever the SCM trigger sees a change, that it replaces the job it queued up with a new job, with the newer SCM revision. I don't want it running a new instance with the next change, and I don't want a ton of jobs queued up.

Basically, I want the job to run in a loop, and only pause if there are no SCM changes.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `Quiet period` option which is under `Advanced Project Options` section.

[image]

You can set the value (in *seconds*) for `Quiet period` as per your requirement. This will help you reduce the frequency of builds.

Comment: The problem with the quiet period is that it always waits. That's not what I'm looking for. What I want is that when the job finishes, a new job starts with all new SCM changes at that point in time. I don't care for the job that gets triggered after the first SCM poll which reveals changes. Alternatively, if the SCM trigger can simply "add on" to an already queued task, that's fine too.

Comment: ... oh and the reason I don't just want to retrigger the same build at the end is because I do want the job to not run when there are no SCM changes ...